# How to hide a text box with a dynamic ID from another controller event handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an AddRow() method which generates a check box and a text box for each row in the table, I need to control the text visibility by checking the check box in the same row.

that seemed to be easy for the first while, since I can get the targeted text box ID but I dont know how to do it now.

here is my method:

```
 private void AddRow(int nRowIndex, string strPaymentStatus,string PaymentRemark)
                {  
    // checkBox -----------------------------------------------------------------
    CheckBox objCheckBox = new CheckBox();
    objCheckBox.ID = strBillID;
    objCheckBox.Checked = false;
    objCheckBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbxPaymentStatus_CheckedChanged);
    objCheckBox.AutoPostBack = true;


// textBox----------------------------------------------------------                
  TextBox objTbxRemark = new TextBox();
objTbxRemark.ID = BillID;
  objTbxRemark.AutoPostBack = true;
}
```

CheckBox handler:

```
protected void cbxPaymentStatus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
// here I can get the BillID (textBox ID) by a query, but I need to control its visibility from here
       }
```

any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use

`Page.FindControl("id")`

If you can reconstruct the correct id. They probably follow some kind of pattern based on the parents controls

The you have to cast to TextBox

```
TextBox txt = Page.FindControl("id") as TextBox ;

txt.Visible =...
```

Comment: thank you so much, but I still need to control the visibility,

Comment: You also need to cast the control to TextBox

Comment: somthing like Page.FindControl("id").visible